# How to wait for downloading thread to finish and then return without blocking UI thread?

Tags: multithreading, android-asynctask, android

I am trying to make a class to download an image, store it and then return it as a `Drawable`. The file need not be downloaded multiple times, but only just the first time.

Here is my class :

```
package com.ishan.drawabletest;
..........................
public class DrawableProvider extends ContextWrapper{

Drawable resultDrawable;

public DrawableProvider(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

public Drawable get(final String fileURL) {
    // File name that is being downloaded
    String downloadedFileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    final String imagePath = getFilesDir() + "/" + downloadedFileName;

    // Checking if the file exists or not
    final File file = new File(imagePath);
    if(file.exists()) {
        // The image already exists, have to only return it by converting into drawable
        resultDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath);
        return resultDrawable;
    } else {
        // The image doesn't exists already.
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Downloading the image here
                    ..................
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                resultDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath);
            }
        };
        t.start();
        // Waiting for the thread to finish before returning using join
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultDrawable;
    }
}
}
```

and this class is called and used like this. :

```
ImageView permanentImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.permaImageView);
    DrawableProvider dp = new DrawableProvider(this);
    permanentImageView.setImageDrawable(dp.get("http://youthvibe2014server.herokuapp.com/public/selenaGomez.jpg"));
```

It works fine for the cases when the image is already available. The problem is that if I **do not wait** ( i.e. if join is removed ) for the thread to finish and return immediately, then the screen does not contains an Image not even the default image (defined in XML) which should be there till the time the download finishes.

It looks like this.

[image: The screen without the image or even without the default image.]

I guess it is like this because my `get` method isn't waiting for the thread to finish and returning `null`, thus the `permanentImageView` is containing `null`.

But if **I do wait** for the thread to finish. The screen eventually displays the downloaded image, but for the time being it goes blank, and looks like this. :

[image: The blank screen when waiting for thread to finish]

I guess this is because when I am waiting for the thread to finish my UI thread is blocked for the time being.

I can't use `AsyncTask` since I am extending `ContextWrapper` and thus can't also extend `AsyncTask`. Is there a way to wait for my thread to finish and then return without blocking my UI thread ?

Comment: follow @CommonsWare advice and use an asyncTask.  Especially b/c it's more user friendly to someone just learning.  As to why your default image is not showing when you don't wait (t.join), it's because you're returning null when your function returns before the image has been set, and i'm sure you go on to use said null, to null out your default image.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use AsyncTask since I am extending ContextWrapper and thus can't also extend AsyncTask.

So, get rid of of `ContextWrapper`. You are not using it for its intended purpose anyway. Inheriting from it is not doing anything useful for you, so inherit from `AsyncTask`.

Or, better yet, use any one of a seemingly infinite number of existing libraries that does this work for you.

Comment: How can I use `getFilesDir()` if I am not using `ContextWrapper`, because `getFilesDir()` seems to be not defined when I am extending `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: @Ishan: `getFilesDir()` is a method on `Context`, such as the `this` you are passing into your `DrawableProvider` class. `getFilesDir()` returns a `File`. Pass the `File` into the constructor of your `AsyncTask`. Or, if you prefer, pass the `File` object to `execute()` on your `AsyncTask` instance, which will deliver the `File` to you in your `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 0):

One Possible Solution : send the Activity to your class and use

```
activity.RunOnUiThread(Runnable runnable)
```

in the runnable you can inform the user like a Callback. 
you can call this function from a Background Thread.

[RunOnUiThread API Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

after downloading the Image

```
resultDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath);
```

place the RunOnUIThread and create callback to the Fragment/Activity. this callback infrom the UI that the Image is ready so you can place it inside the ImageView.

for example create a function that called

```
public Drawable getDrawable() {
      return resultDrawable;

}
```

in the Callback itself use this function to place the Image inside the ImageView.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the code for downloading should run on UI thread?

Comment: Update the answer. It's a little unclear I guess. :)